# What is this random space under my div and how do I remove it?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a rectangle card with a graph on it. I've moved it to the right using the transform and left property. I've tried all sorts of things but nothing seems to fix it.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  background-color: #D7DBDD;
}

#chart {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%, -73%);
  max-width: 47vw;
}

#rectangle {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-2%, 25%);
  width: 49vw;
  height: 63vh;
  background: #ECF0F1;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 50px 15px #BDC3C7;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle"></div>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

All help would be appreciated and I am still learning CSS so please keep that in mind.

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's unclear what "random space" you mean, and to which div you are referring.

Comment: A screenshot using [LightShot](https://app.prntscr.com/) or another app might be a good addition to your answer.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, here: https://prnt.sc/1dieo6g @GlebKemarsky

Comment: Why are you using `transform` ? Also if your graph is meant to be inside the rectangle, why isn't the chart div inside the rectangle div?

Comment: @lad21 Unfortunately, it is still unclear what exactly is wrong in the screenshot and what result you need. It is also unclear why you chose such a solution for CSS and how you got the values for the CSS properties. We know nothing about your task. Try adding a detailed explanation. You can edit your answer to add something new.